# How to subview a camera view?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, camera, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller

I am making an app that will let the user see themselves in a 'mirror' (the front facing camera on the device).  I know of multiple ways of making a UIImageViewController with a view overlay, but I want my app to have it be the opposite way.  In my app, I want the camera view to be a subview of the main view, without the shutter animation or the ability to capture photos or take videos and without it being full screen.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is to not use the built-in UIImagePickerController, but rather use the `AVFoundation` classes.

You want to create an `AVCaptureSession` and set the appropriate outputs and inputs. Once it's configured you can get an `AVCapturePreviewLayer` which can be added to a view that you have configured in your view controller.  The preview layer has a number of properties that allow you to control how the preview is displayed.

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
AVCaptureOutput *output = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
[session addOutput:output];

//Setup camera input
NSArray *possibleDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
//You could check for front or back camera here, but for simplicity just grab the first device
AVCaptureDevice *device = [possibleDevices objectAtIndex:0];
NSError *error = nil;
// create an input and add it to the session
AVCaptureDeviceInput* input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error]; //Handle errors

//set the session preset 
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium; //Or other preset supported by the input device   
[session addInput:input];

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
//Set the preview layer frame
previewLayer.frame = self.cameraView.bounds;
//Now you can add this layer to a view of your view controller
[self.cameraView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer]
[session startRunning];
```

You can then use the `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler:` of the   output device to capture an image.

For more information on how AVFoundation is structured and examples on how to do this in more detail checkout the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2).
Apple's [AVCamDemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) lays all of this out as well

Comment: I get an error 'No visible @interface for 'CALayer' declares the selector 'addSubLayer:'' on the last line when I run the code.  What is wrong?

Comment: You will need to import QuartzCore .. `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in order to access the CALayer properties.

Comment: Now I'm getting the error:No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'objextAtIndex:'  on the `AVCaptureDevice *device = [possibleDevices objextAtIndex:0];` line along with the same error as before, but with quartzCore imported.  What's wrong and thank you for your response in advanced.

Comment: Have you imported the AVFoundation framework and headers? `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` and add the `AVFoundation.framework`?

Comment: Yes I did.  Not sure if helps, but it can't find 'possibleDevices' when I command-click on it (also, the error is an 'ARC Semantic Issue').

Comment: Can you let me have a look at more of your code? I am not sure what's going on.. but I need to see it to figure it out. (use pastebin or something like that to share it)

Comment: [Here is my code](http://pastebin.com/WTJRJ1ZU), I commented below the lines that are giving me the errors what the errors are.  Thank you for taking the time to debug this for me.

Comment: Just a guess, but shouldn't changing `objextAtIndex` to be `objectAtIndex` help you out for one of your issues?

Comment: Thanks fatty, I will change that in the answer.  @coryginsberg Sorry I haven't had a chance to look at your code.. I will do that now

Comment: @coryginsberg So (as fatty said) it was `objextAtIndex` instead of `objectAtIndex` and `addSubLayer`instead of `addSublayer`.  You will also need to set the frame of the preview layer.  Something like `previewLayer.frame = self.readerView.bounds`. Also you will need to call `[session startRunning]` after you are finished with your session configuration. You will also want to keep the `AVCaptureSession` around, probably in a property, make sure to clean it up properly.  Hopefully that helps, you should be able to find a lot of this info in the [AVFoundation Guide](http://m1nd.se/NmMJfw)

Comment: Can you provide more information about the captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection ?