# UIAlertView crashs in iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

recently i start receiving crash reports for UIAlertView only by users that use iOS 8.3

Crashlytics reports:

> Fatal Exception: UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation
>   Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [_UIAlertShimPresentingViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES

The line where that crash happens is [alertView show] :

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
```

that code is in the app for a long time and now it starts crashing. Did anyone experience a similar behaviour and has fixed the problem?

Comment: Its deprecated in iOS 8.

Comment: i know - but deprecated things should still be working and it worked well in ios 8.0, 8.1 and 8.2. Since my App also supports iOS 7 and i don't want to introduce conditionals for the UIAlertView calls i decided to still keep the old code as long as its supported

Comment: I get the same error with UIAlertControllers. Subclassing UIAlertController (or UIAlertView) should fix the issue.

Comment: @Maxwell Apple explicitly says __not__ to subclass `UIAlertView` or `UIAlertController` in the docs. See the answers below.

Comment: @stevekohls You're right. Which class am I supposed to override those methods? I tried the view controller that's presenting the UIAlertController, but the crash persists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try by implementing this

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
   return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

check this also : [Orientation issue in Lanscape mode while opening camera in iOS 7 in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774068/orientation-issue-in-lanscape-mode-while-opening-camera-in-ios7-in-iphone)

Comment: I thought i had this in, but i accidentaly used UIDeviceOrientationPortrait instead of UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait.

Comment: Added above method but still issue with my app

Comment: This solved my issue. Replacing Alertview will be a hell lot of work :)

Answer (score 10):

The main thing is :

> UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation Supported orientations **has no common orientation** with the application

It means you have somewhere implemented

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIDeviceOrientationPortrait; // or UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
}
```

UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait = **0**

In that function MUST be returned **Mask** like:

UIInterfaceOrientation**Mask**Portrait which is **1**

Answer (score 1):

Better than this you should start using `UIAlertController`. It has much better functionality and also for `UIAlertAction` you don't have to include delegate methods.

```
UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:@"Info"
                             message:@"You are using UIAlertController"
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                    actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                    {
                        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                    }];

UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                       {
                           [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                       }];

[alert addAction:ok];

[alert addAction:cancel];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

***Important***: **UIAlertView** is deprecated in iOS 8. *(Note that **UIAlertViewDelegate** is also deprecated.)* To create and manage alerts in iOS 8 and later, instead use **UIAlertController** with a preferredStyle of **UIAlertControllerStyleAlert**.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html

Answer (score 0):

After trying the solutions here, none of them worked for me. I'm supporting iOS 6-8 in an app, and, more than that, use some libraries that use UIAlertView internally, so simply conditionally compiling to use UIAlertController when available was not an option.

I came up with a solution that solved the problem for me. Your mileage may vary. I include the header file in the Header Prefix file so that it's sure to be included anywhere a UIAlertView is shown.

I'm posting this here for anyone who's stumbling on this problem and the solutions found around the net don't work. Hopefully it's helpful.

https://gist.github.com/joshhudnall/cdc89b61d0a545c85d1d

Answer (score 0):

I created a helper for displaying UIAlertView when before iOS8 and UIAlertController after iOS8, this solves the rotation crash and also displays nicely in all versions.

https://github.com/dannyshmueli/DSAlertDisplayer