# unwanted ios 8 app rotation on certain devices

Tags: swift, ios8, landscape-portrait, autorotate

I'm writing an app in Swift on ios 8 that I want to make sure only works in Portrait mode on all devices (for now). I have "Portrait" selected as the only Device Orientation under "Deployment Info" for the app, as such :

[image]

It works fine on simulators and iPhone 6 Plus; however, when testing on an iPad Mini, the orientation changes even though it shouldn't. 
Is this a known issue or am I missing a configuration somewhere?

Would love any input. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

paste these methods in the ViewController of each view:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
}
```

And let me know If it works for you.

Comment: That worked, but caused other problems - similar to the ones listed below; The solutions there helped straighten things out. Thank you. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629106/ios-8-3-supported-orientations-crashs