# Crash on shouldAutorotate() method when UIAlertview show in Landscape viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, orientation, uialertview, landscape, shouldautorotate

I am working on a app in which I am using only one orientation which is Portrait. This is device orientation setting:

[image]

But In my app there is Video player (Custom Player of `MPMoviePlayerViewController`) which I wanted to show in Landscape Right mode only and It should not be rotated.
This is working fine, I mean this Custom Player is showing in Landscape Right perfectly, but when I am using an `UIAlertview` then application is crashed on this method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {


    return NO;

}
```

These are some other orientation methods :

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight; // or Right of course
}

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 90000
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
#else
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
#endif
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

I am getting this Error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [UIAlertController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'
```

Comment: might be that help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534105/uialertview-crashs-in-ios-8-3 and https://www.google.co.in/search?q=[UIAlertController+shouldAutorotate]+is+returning+YES%27&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ZxtIV-6uFKfT8geUpoiwDg

Answer (score 1):

iHTCboy's answer fixed it for me after converting to swift.

In swift 4:

```
extension UIAlertController {

override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { return .all }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS8 :UIAlertController

```
#import "UIAlertController+Portrait.h"

@implementation UIAlertController (Portrait)

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution 1. Go to info.plist and delete the other orientations which you don't need :-

[image]
Solution 2. Use following code(where your) :-

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    UIViewController *vC = self.topViewController;
    return vC.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
   UIViewController *vC = self.topViewController;
   return [vC shouldAutorotate];
}
```

Comment: The question already says that Info.plist specifies only portrait orientation.